# Error of Trapezium Rule

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series

Given that $h=\frac{b-a}2, c=\frac{b+a}2 $ , $Err=T-I$ where $T=h[f(a)+f(b)]$ and $I=\int_a^bf(x) dx $

Using:

$Err= \int_a^b(x-c)f'(x) dx                   $

Show that

$Err =\frac12\int_a^b[h^2-(x-c)^2]f''(x) dx           $

The question asks to use integration by parts "the other way around". I am struggling to get from the first part to the second

Answer (score 0):

$$Err = \int_a^b(x-c)f'(x)dx= \int_a^bf'(x)d\frac{(x-c)^2}2=f'(x)\frac{(x-c)^2}2 \Big|_a^b-\int_a^b\frac{(x-c)^2}2f''(x)dx=\frac12(f'(x)(x-c)^2 \Big|_a^b-\int_a^b(x-c)^2f''(x)dx)=\frac12(f'(b)(b-c)^2- f'(a)(a-c)^2-\int_a^b(x-c)^2f''(x)dx)=\frac12\int_a^b(h^2-(x-c)^2)f''(x)dx$$